# Is there a Pathfinder first edition Druid archetype that enhances Wild shape generically?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, wild-shape, archetype

I would like to know about wild shape in Pathfinder first edition. The Shifter class in that system seems restrictive and not nearly as flexible at run-time as Dungeons & Dragons third edition's Shifter prestige class or version 3.5's Master of Many Forms prestige class. I found Ancient Guardian and Feral Shifter which appear to enhance wild shape, but do not allow additional forms to turn into. Is there an archetype that increases the available form options for wild shape?

Answer (score 4):

One archetype published by Paizo, technically: the [Naga Aspirant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-nagaji/naga-aspirant-druid-naga), which requires being a [Nagaji](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-nagaji/), adds the ability to become a naga without otherwise affecting wild shape.

And, one 3rd party archetype I've found: the [Ossuarite](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/forest-guardian-press-druid-archetypes/ossuarite-druid-archetype), which has an explicit and strong connection to undeath.

Beyond that, I can't find any and don't know of any.

The [PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/) has a list of all of the [archetypes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Core-classes/Druid/#archetypes_alternate_class_features) that Paizo published along with a fair number published by 3rd party publishers. Where it shines is that each archetype in the list shows what's changed (or removed), so it's a fairly straightforward job to go though those that change some of the Wild Shape entries, at least for a first pass.

[Draconic Druid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/draconic-druid-druid-archetype/) doesn't strictly increase the available forms, instead granting uses of a draconic version of themselves or becoming a medium/large dragon per [form of the dragon 1 or 2](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/form-of-the-dragon-i).

The [Kraken Caller](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/kraken-caller-druid-archetype) similarly restricts the list of target creatures (to "animals with the aquatic or water subtype or that have the amphibious special quality") while allowing the druid to instead grow tentacles that can be used to attack or climb, swim, or perform dirty tricks or combat maneuvers.

The [Toxicologist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/toxicologist-druid-archetype) can change into vermin instead of elementals or plants.

The [Cave Druid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/cave-druid) trades being able to take plant form for being able to take the form of an ooze. Their wild shape is also delayed 2 levels.

The [Desert Druid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/desert-druid) trades plants for vermin and has their wild shape delayed 2 levels.

The [Mountain Druid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/mountain-druid) trades plants for giant forms (as [giant form 1 and 2](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/giant-form-i)) and have wild shape delayed 2 levels.

The [Treesinger Druid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/elf/treesinger-druid-elf), which requires being an elf, trades being able to become an animal or elemental for enhanced plant options.